# Detectar si un campo se actualiza con Javascript o Jquery, sin usar trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una plantilla muy extensa, y hay un formulario que actualiza el valor de un campo de texto con Javascript o Jquery, esta función no he logrado localizarla, y necesito detectar cuando este campo es actualizado, he probado con todas estas funciones, pero no esta detectando cuando es actualizado.

¿Pueden ayudarme a encontrar el motivo, o alguna solución, por que no esta detectando cuando el campo es actualizado desde Javascript pero si se detecta cuando se actualizado cuando escribo y hago click fuera del campo?

**IMPORTANTE:** El valor 90,000 que se agrega dinámicamente, lo haceuna función específica, que no he podido encontrar y necesito resolver urgentemente por cuestiones de tiempo de la manera más rápida y sencilla, y es tratar de detectar si el valor cambió con Javascript y no con acciones del usuario.

```js
$(function(){

/**
 * Actualización automática del formulario, funcion no encontrada
 * IMPORTANTE: $('#long').val('90.000').trigger('change') no puedo usar esto por que la
   Funcion que agrega este valor no la he encontrado y es muy extenso el proyecto, quiero una              alternativa rápida desde Javascript o Jquery
 */
setTimeout(function(){
  // Value updated automatically
  $('#long').val("90.000");
}, 2000);

/**
 * Detecta cuando el campo es actualizado
 */
$('input#long').on('change', function(){
  alert("Updated");
});

$(':input').on('change', function(){
  alert("Updated");
});

$('input#long').change(function(){
  alert("Updated");
});

$(document).on('change', 'input#long', function(){
  alert("Updated");
});  

$(document).on('change', 'input', function(){
  alert("Updated");
}); 

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="long">
```

Answer (score 1):

El evento `change` no se lanza cuando el valor es cambiado con `$.val()`. Por lo que no podrias usarlo para detectar cuando cambie su valor de forma dinamica. Ver ejemplo:

```js
$("input").on("change", function(e){
  $("p").html("valor: " + $(this).val());
});
var v = 0;
$("button").on("click", function(){
  $("input").val(v++);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="click me!">
<button>Click me!</button>
<p></p>
```

Por lo que tendrias que sobrescribir la funcion `$.val()` para que despues de que cambie el valor lance el evento `change` y así poder detectarlo. Te dejo el codigo que encontre en [una respuesta de la comunidad en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23635867/8067370):

```
(function($){
    var originalVal = $.fn.val;
    $.fn.val = function(){
        var result =originalVal.apply(this,arguments);
        if(arguments.length>0)
            $(this).change(); // OR with custom event $(this).trigger('value-changed');
        return result;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

De preferencia coloca este codigo antes de que se ejecute cualquier codigo de tu proyecto, de esta forma no tendras problemas. Ve la diferencia:

```js
(function($){
    var originalVal = $.fn.val;
    $.fn.val = function(){
        var result =originalVal.apply(this,arguments);
        if(arguments.length>0)
            $(this).change(); // OR with custom event $(this).trigger('value-changed');
        return result;
    };
})(jQuery);

$("input").on("change", function(e){
  $("p").html("valor: " + $(this).val());
});
var v = 0;
$("button").on("click", function(){
  $("input").val(v++);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="click me!">
<button>Click me!</button>
<p></p>
```

Ahora lo unico que tienes que hacer es detectar si el nuevo valor es "90,000" entonces lo estableces en el valor que más te convenga o directamente lo omites.

Saludos!

Comment: Hola Jesús, gracias pero el valor 90.000 es automático, no lo agrego yo, lo agrega una función, mira en los detalles lo he comentado, no tengo una forma de poder modificar esa función por el momento, por lo que requiero es lograr detectar si cambio el campo automático y detectar esto con Javascript.

Comment: Buenas @Learningandsharing, si entendí tu problema. La función $.val es nativa de JQuery por lo que, en caso de que la función de la que hablas la utilice, solo tendrías que sobrescribir la función $.val antes de que mandes a llamar cualquier otro script para poder detectar el cambio. Lamentablemente no hay otra forma (que yo conozca) de detectar cuando un campo cambie de valor por algún evento JavaScript. Saludos!